# Can someone please help me with these shell script lines. I can' understand what is the use DEBUG in these lines

Tags: linux, bash

```sh
# Define DEBUG=true on cmdline, if needed

DEBUG=${DEBUG:-false}
[[ ${DEBUG} = true ]] || DEBUG="false"
```

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html for the `${DEBUG:-false}` Loop up the `${parameter:-word}`

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The first assignment sets the variable `DEBUG` to `false` if the contents of `DEBUG` is empty. Please note that if `DEBUG` has not been initialized yet, it is also considered as empty and thus will receive the `false` value.

The second line uses the OR operator using `||`, it is exactly the same as:

```sh
if ! [[ ${DEBUG} = true ]]
then
  DEBUG="false"
fi
```

In other words, it assigns the value `false` to your variable if and only `DEBUG` does NOT equal to `true`.

In the end, the purpose of this code is to define the `DEBUG` variable to either `true` or `false` and nothing else, using the default value `false` if the variable does not contain a boolean value.

### Improvements

I think the first assignment is pointless because if the variable was empty at the beginning of this code, then the last line will assign the variable to `false` anyways.

Also, the `${DEBUG}` should be protected with quotes, e.g. `[[ "${DEBUG}" = true ]]` instead of `[[ ${DEBUG} = true ]]` because your script may not work properly if the variable contains whitespaces.

A bit overkill maybe, but I encourage checking case sensitivity and use a fallback code.

Let’s say the user defines `DEBUG=TRUE` (uppercase) prior to calling your script, the value of `DEBUG` will be forced to `false`. I guess the user would not be very pleased.

The following code solves all those issues:

```sh
# Define DEBUG=true on cmdline, if needed

DEBUG=${DEBUG,,} # Force the variable to lowercase
[[ "${DEBUG}" = true ]] || DEBUG=false
```